# Google apps sso into office 365

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365, google-apps, federation

I am trying to let my google apps users login into office365 using google apps credentials but I am unable to find setup page on microsoft azure ad or office 365 account I followed https://support.google.com/a/answer/6363817?hl=en instructions but could not find instructions on Office 365 side. Does any one know where to find the setting page.

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling this for a couple of days now.
The key is: you must use PowerShell to do the AzureAD settings:
Install AzureAD plugin for Powershell as described in the lower part of the page here: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj151815.aspx

Then this guys instructions helped me greatly:
http://www.viewds.com/blog/making-office-365-work-with-an-external-saml-identity-provider.html

I'm at a point where I get redirected from office.com to Google's login page as soon as I type my email address with our company domain. but then the login fails (but it worked 1 single time oddly enough). Let me know if you get any further!

Cheers
:Phil